# Select a previous file in a folder and copy it to a new one

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do the following:

- Allow the user to select any number of files, in any format, and copy them to a new folder.
- Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist. In this case, the folder name should be given by the content of the C2 & C3 cells (Range("C2").Value & Range("C3").Text & "\").

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim strDirname As String
Dim strDefpath As String
Dim strPathname As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As FileDialog
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String

strDirname = Range("C2").Value & Range("C3").Text

MkDir strDefpath & "\" & strDirname
strPathname = strDefpath & "\" & strDirname & "\" & strFilename

Set sFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

sDFolder = strDirname & "\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If Not .Show Then Exit Sub
    Set xFolder = FSO.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1))
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        On Error Resume Next
        xRow = Application.Match(xFile.Name, Range("A:A"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

I know the error is here...

```
Set xFolder = FSO.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1))
```

...because I'm asking it to get a file, not a folder.

Comment: You never define `strDefpath`

Comment: You want the user to select a file but yet the following line uses the same variable as a folder... maybe you mean/want the user to select a Folder so yu can loop over the files inside?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear to me what you are trying to do but, if you intend to select a folder, you have to use it

```
    Application.FileDialog (msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

instead of

```
    Application.FileDialog (msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code shows so little resemblance to what you Q asks for, I've disregarded it.

This code follows the description.  You may need to alter certain details to fully match your needs

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim FilePicker As FileDialog
    Dim DefaultPath As String
    Dim DestinationFolderName As String
    Dim SelectedFile As Variant
    Dim DestinationFolder As Folder
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject

    DefaultPath = "C:\Data" ' <~~ update to suit, or get it from somewhere else

    ' Validate Default Path
    If Right$(DefaultPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        DefaultPath = DefaultPath & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(DefaultPath) Then Exit Sub

    ' Get Destination Folder, add trailing \ if required
    DestinationFolderName = Range("C2").Value & Range("C3").Value
    If Right$(DestinationFolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        DestinationFolderName = DestinationFolderName & Application.PathSeparator
    End If

    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject

    ' Get reference to Destination folder, create it if required
    If FSO.FolderExists(DefaultPath & DestinationFolderName) Then
        Set DestinationFolder = FSO.GetFolder(DefaultPath & DestinationFolderName)
    Else
        Set DestinationFolder = FSO.CreateFolder(DefaultPath & DestinationFolderName)
    End If

    ' File Selection Dialog
    Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With FilePicker
        .AllowMultiSelect = True ' allow user to select multiple files
        .InitialFileName = DefaultPath ' set initial folder for dialog
        If .Show = False Then Exit Sub ' check if user cancels
        For Each SelectedFile In .SelectedItems ' loop over selected files
            If SelectedFile Like DefaultPath & "*" Then 'Optional: disallow browsing higher than default folder
                FSO.CopyFile SelectedFile, DefaultPath & DestinationFolderName, True  ' Copy file, overwrite is it exists
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to adapt a few things but it worked. Thank you very much.